# Vue issue navigationg to and from error page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vue-router

I am working on a single page application with vuex and vue routing.

Current Setup:

- navigation via dropdown menu and matching searchstring from a textfield
- on search-btn click navigate to a result page with the search-text as parameter
- in the created() method of that result page fire action to the api
  -- if the request was successful continue to load the page
  -- if the request was not successul redirect to a "NotFound" error page (for example misspelled word was not found in database)

**the problem**

I cannot navigate back again once I hit the NotFound page. It will try to load the previous page with /result/wrong_word path that will again lead to the NotFound page. How can I solve this? Is there a way to manipulate the history stack of vue router?

in router.js:

`mode: 'history'`

Comment: I believe you are using this.$router.push(`/result/${word}`); with history mode, there are some configurations that we need to make to server: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations

Comment: I am pretty new to all this and I cannot figure out how these configurations will help? What part of these configurations would be helpful in my case?

Comment: You are currently in a development environment or production server deployed environment?

Comment: development environment